# selenium automation framework, chrome does not load page

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phpunit, selenium-chromedriver

We are using phpunit-selenium framework for automation using chrome browser. Everything works fine but few times, 2-3 times in day for uncertain time, chrome does not load page. Framework launch browser but after that nothing happen. Same setup start working again after few minutes wait. This is happerning from last 3-4 months.

Anyone have idea about this issue.

Comment: Please share your selenium code.

Comment: share your script or screenshot...

Comment: I can not share framework code, but issue is that same setup working fine for all days except 3-4 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Without the code I can't be certain what is causing Chrome not to load the page certain times you navigate to a url. In the past if I do a repeated navigate, click, or almost any Selenium task a few thousand times it won't work every time.

***Try updating your Chrome driver to the latest version***. [Chrome Driver Download](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html)

2.9 is currently the newest version.

If that doesn't work try.

**C#:**

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl('url');

//Waits up to 30 sec for page to load. 
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(readystate_complete)

if(driver.url != 'url')
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl('url');
```